# Interruption of signal from mac to external monitor after changing resolution

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport, resolution

I have a dell S2721QS 4K monitor. I connected my MacBook Pro to a Lenovo Thinkpad docking station using a USB-C to USB-C connection. I then connected the DisplayPort from the dock to the HDMI port on the monitor (it is a DP to HDMI cable). The resolution for the monitor was set to 1080p. I changed it from 1080p to 3840x2160 at 30 Hz and the screen would go off for a second and come back, and then all of a sudden there is a distortion and constant lack of signal. Like it keeps coming and going, and when it does come it is extremely distorted. I also tried changing the monitor's resolution to 2560x1440 at 60 Hz and it does the same. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?